# Why does $T$ being an unbiased estimator for $g(\theta)$ imply that $g(\theta) = ET = \int T(\mathbf{y}) f_\theta(\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y}$?

Tags: unbiased-estimator, cramer-rao

I am currently studying the **Cramer-Rao lower bound**. My notes say the following:

> **Theorem: Cramer-Rao lower bound**
> Let $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ have a joint distribution $f_\theta (\mathbf{y})$, where $f_\theta (\mathbf{y})$ satisfies the following two regularity conditions:
>
> 1. The support supp$f_\theta (\mathbf{y})$ does not depend on $\theta$;
> 2. for any statistic $T = T(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$ with a finite $E_\theta \lvert T \rvert$, integration w.r.t. $\mathbf{y}$ and differentiation w.r.t. $\theta$ in calculating $(E[T])_\theta^\prime$ can be interchanged, that is,
>    $$(E[T])_\theta^\prime = \dfrac{d}{d\theta} \int T(\mathbf{y})f_\theta (\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y} = \int T(\mathbf{y})f_\theta^\prime (\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y}$$
>    Let $T$ be an unbiased estimator for $\theta$, with a finite variance. Then
>    $$\text{Var}(T) \ge \dfrac{1}{I(\theta)},$$
>    where $I(\theta) = E[(\ln(f_\theta(\mathbf{Y})_\theta^\prime)^2]$ is called the **Fisher information number**.
>    More generally, if $T$ is an unbiased estimator for $g(\theta)$, where $g(\cdot)$ is differentiable, then,
>    $$\text{Var}(T) \ge \dfrac{(g^\prime(\theta))^2}{I(\theta)}$$
>    **Proof: Cramer-Rao lower bound**
>    Since $T$ is an unbiased estimator for $g(\theta)$, we have
>    $$g(\theta) = ET = \int T(\mathbf{y}) f_\theta(\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y},$$
>    and, under regularity conditions,
>    $$g^\prime(\theta) = (E[T])_\theta^\prime = \dfrac{d}{d \theta} \int T(\mathbf{y}) f_\theta(\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y} = \int T(\mathbf{y}) f_\theta^\prime (\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y} = \int T(\mathbf{y})(\ln \left[ f_\theta (\mathbf{y})\right]_\theta^\prime f_\theta (\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y} = E[T(\mathbf{Y})(\ln [f_\theta(\mathbf{Y})])_\theta^\prime ]$$

I am confused by this part:

> Since $T$ is an unbiased estimator for $g(\theta)$, we have
> $$g(\theta) = ET = \int T(\mathbf{y}) f_\theta(\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y}$$

Why does $T$ being an unbiased estimator for $g(\theta)$ imply that $g(\theta) = ET = \int T(\mathbf{y}) f_\theta(\mathbf{y}) \ d\mathbf{y}$?

---

### EDIT

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Definition :

"... or equivalently, if the expected value of the estimator matches that of the parameter." In this case, the expected value  of the estimator does *not* match the parameter, but rather a *function* of the parameter. So there seems to be some disconnect here between what's in these notes and the Wikipedia definition of an unbiased estimator.

Comment: What definition(s) and formula(s) do you know for expectation?

Comment: Re the edit: you misinterpret Wikipedia.  What is being estimated here is $g(\theta).$  *A fortiori,* the estimator is unbiased if its expectation equals $g(\theta).$  Indeed, when $g$ is a one-to-one function, $g(\theta)$ *is* a parameter.

Comment: @whuber Ok, that makes sense. I think I was confused because $\theta$ itself is usually the parameter being estimated, but, in this case, the "parameter" is $g(\theta)$.

Answer (score 3):

This is the definition of unbiasedness.

Comment: Care to elaborate? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Definition

Comment: The Wiki already mentioned, that being unbiased means the expected value of the estimator being equal to the true (unknown) parameter value.  Maybe you read the text wrong?  It is $T$ (a statistic), not $Y$ (the raw data), that is the unbiased estimator.

Comment: See my edit. "... or equivalently, if the expected value of the estimator matches that of the parameter." In this case, the expected value of the estimator does not match the parameter, but rather a function of the parameter. So there seems to be some disconnect here between what's in these notes and the Wikipedia definition of an unbiased estimator.